# Getting count of object based on condition

Tags: javascript

I have an object containing a bunch of similar objects. I would like to get the count of the object only for those where a object property (status) is of a given value (true).  For instance, the count of the below object is 3.

```
{
 6:{"name":"Mary", "status":true},
 2:{"name":"Mike", "status":true},
 1:{"name":"John", "status":false},
 4:{"name":"Mark", "status":true},
 5:{"name":"Jane", "status":false}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You can upvote halpful questions and answers (by clicking on the arrows) and you can accept answers that solve your problem by clicking on the gree checkmark next to it. This helps organize Stackoverflow and italso makes everyone happy.

Comment: By the way, what have you tried here?

Comment: I did the following, and it works, but I expect there are bettersolutions. Sorry for the mixed up post.    var count=0;
for (var o in myObject)
{count=count+myObject[o].status;}

Answer (score 8):

I recognize you are iterating over an object, not an array, but since the others provide solutions for arrays I recon a solution with array.reduce is in place. Works in most modern browsers (IE9+)

```
var myArray = [
 {"name":"Mary", "status":true},
 {"name":"Mike", "status":true},
 {"name":"John", "status":false},
 {"name":"Mark", "status":true},
 {"name":"Jane", "status":false}
];

var result = myArray.reduce(function(previousValue, currentObject){
    return previousValue + (currentObject.status ? 1: 0); 
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifically:

```
var i = 0;
var count = 0;
while (i < array.length) {
    if (array[i]['status'] == true) count += 1; 
    i += 1;
}
```

---

More generally, you can use some functional programming:

```
function count_matches(array, func) {
    var i = 0;
    var count = 0;
    while (i < array.length) {
        if (func(array[i])) count += 1;
        i += 1;
    }
    return count;
}

function status_true(obj) {
    return obj['status'] == true;
}

count_matches(array, status_true);
```

The above snippets do the same thing, but the latter is more flexible/potentially neater.

Comment: You  could also do i++, to save a couple characters. :D

Answer (score 0):

just loop over the array and count how many times the status property is true.

```
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < yourArray.length; i++){
   var current = yourArray[i];
   if (current.status) count++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

LinqJs would work (might be too much for the simple example posted in the question) -

http://linqjs.codeplex.com/

```
var jsonArray = [
{ "user": { "id": 100, "screen_name": "d_linq" }, "text": "to objects" },
{ "user": { "id": 130, "screen_name": "c_bill" }, "text": "g" },
{ "user": { "id": 155, "screen_name": "b_mskk" }, "text": "kabushiki kaisha" },
{ "user": { "id": 301, "screen_name": "a_xbox" }, "text": "halo reach" }]


// ["b_mskk:kabushiki kaisha", "c_bill:g", "d_linq:to objects"]
var queryResult = Enumerable.From(jsonArray)
.Where(function (x) { return x.user.id < 200 })
.OrderBy(function (x) { return x.user.screen_name })
.Select(function (x) { return x.user.screen_name + ':' + x.text })
.ToArray();

// shortcut! string lambda selector
var queryResult2 = Enumerable.From(jsonArray)
.Where("$.user.id < 200")
.OrderBy("$.user.screen_name")
.Select("$.user.screen_name + ':' + $.text")
.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {
 6:{"name":"Mary", "status":true},
 2:{"name":"Mike", "status":true},
 1:{"name":"John", "status":false},
 4:{"name":"Mark", "status":true},
 5:{"name":"Jane", "status":false}
};
var count = 0;
for (var prop in obj) {
  if(obj[prop].status === true){
   count += 1; 
  }
}
console.log("Output: "+count);
$("#debug").text("Output: "+count);
```

live demo http://jsbin.com/uwucid/2/edit